# How can I tie the visibility of a pane to another control?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

So I have a two radio buttons. If RadioButton1 is selected, I want Panel1 to be visible and Panel2 to be hidden.  If RadioButton2 is selected, I want Panel2 to be visible and Panel1 to be hidden.  Is there a way to do this without requiring a postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's essentially two ways to do this: completely client-side and server-side with async postback.

**Client-Side:**

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Javascript:

```
toggleDiv = function(id, opt) {
    _id = document.getelementbyid(id);
    if (opt == "show") {
        _id.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        _id.style.display = "hidden";
    }

}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:radiobutton id="rbOne" runat="server" />
<asp:radiobutton id="rbTwo" runat="server" />

<div id="panel1" class="hidden">
    <p>Panel 1</p>
</div>

<div id="panel2" class="hidden">
    <p>Panel 2</p>
</div>
```

Code-Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Apply onclick handlers to the radio buttons
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        rbOne.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleDiv('" & rbOne.ClientId() & "', 'show'); toggleDiv('" & rbTwo.ClientId & "', 'hide');")
        rbTwo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "toggleDiv('" & rbOne.ClientId() & "', 'hide'); toggleDiv('" & rbTwo.ClientId & "', 'show');")
    End If

End Sub
```

---

**Server-Side**

ASPX:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="upRadioButtons" runat="server">
    <asp:radiobutton id="rbOne" runat="server" autopostback="true" />
    <asp:radiobutton id="rbTwo" runat="server" autopostback="true" />

    <asp:multipage id="mvButtonPanels" runat="server">
        <asp:view id="view1" runat="server">
            <p>Panel 1</p>
        </asp:view>
        <asp:view id="view2" runat="server">
            <p>Panel 2</p>
        </asp:view>
    </asp:multipage>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
Protected Sub rbOne_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbOne.CheckedChanged
    mvButtonPanels.ActiveViewIndex = 0
End Sub

Protected Sub rbTwo_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rbTwo.CheckedChanged
    mvButtonPanels.ActiveViewIndex = 1
End Sub
```

There's many other ways to do this, such as using jQuery for the client-side and using a bit less hard-coded logic for the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a little javascript. Add an onclick handler to both radio buttons and call a function to update the view:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio_1" onclick="updateView">Radio 1
<input type="radio" id="radio_2" onclick="updateView">Radio 2

<script>
  function updateView() {
    var radio_1 = document.getElementById("radio_1");
    // etc... get radio 2 and panels the same way
    panel_1.style.display = radio_1.checked ? "block" : "none";
    panel_2.style.display = radio_2.checked ? "block" : "none";
  }
</script>
```